# How to overwrite a file with shell script without using extra device space?

Tags: shell-script, file-copy

I'm trying to overwrite a file using:

`cp source.txt target.txt`

But I get "No space left on device".

I also tried using dd with no success, even with super user.

How can I overwrite using only the space used by the target file?

Comment: Is source larger than target?

Comment: Did you use `dd … >`  or `dd … of=`?

Comment: What operating system is this? What filesystem? The reasons for getting that issue may very well depend on those.